# Can't insert more than 150 rows

Tags: sql, go

I am using go-sql-driver/mysql to insert a ton of movies from the OMDB data dump. I am parsing the data and inserting it with the following code:

```
_, err = database.Query("INSERT INTO `movies` (`name`, `year`, `release_date`, `full_plot`, `genre`, `imdb_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", movie.Name, movie.Year, movie.ReleaseDate, movie.FullPlot, movie.Genre, movie.IMDBID)

if err != nil {
    return false, nil
}
return true, nil
```

It works, but for only 150 rows. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `return false, nil` why aren't you returning the error? There could be some useful information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to discard the error value returned, which you shouldn't do; handle it gracefully. See what the error is, if you're opening too many connections to the DB, you should use a database connection pool and set the `(*DB) SetMaxOpenConns` value.

`(*DB)Query` is typically used for `SELECT` statements that return rows, use `(*DB)Exec` or `(*Stmt)Exec` for your `INSERT`.

I'd advise using a db connection pool, and `(*sql.DB)Prepare` to prepare a statement and run your inserts (even concurrently) using the prepared statement.

See https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare

Comment: Tossing the error is an oversight, thank you, I will look into the prepare function.

Comment: It was too many connections, and exec has fixed it. Thank you.